# How to use HiddenFor in ASP.NET MVC Html Helpers from a custom helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I get error "Cannot resolve symbol 'Hiddenfor'"

How to use HiddenFor in ASP.NET MVC Html Helpers from a custom helper?

```
@helper test (Model model)
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.name, "test")
}
```

Comment: `@Html.Hidden(text)`

Comment: Ok, but Cant I user HTML.HiddenFor in a helper?
Its the same with HTML.DisplayFor

Comment: You should be able to do this no problem. Is it something to do with the 2nd argument "test"? what is that trying to do?